# Does ALTER COLUMN TYPE varchar(N) rewrite the table in Postgres 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, varchar, postgresql-9.6

#### In the past

The way we handled this with Postgres 8.4 was to manually update the `pg_attribute` table:

```
LOCK TABLE pg_attribute IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
UPDATE pg_attribute SET atttypmod = 104
    WHERE attrelid = 'table_name'::regclass AND
          attname = 'column_name';
```

`column_name` was a `varchar(50)` and we wanted a `varchar(100)`, but the table was too enormous (tens of millions of rows) and too heavily used to rewrite.

#### Nowadays

The content and answers around this topic were sparse and outdated for such a (at least anecdotally) common problem.

But, after seeing hints that this might be the case on at least 3 discussions, I've come to think that with newer versions of Postgres (we're on 9.6), you are now able to run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ALTER COLUMN 'column_name' TYPE varchar(100);
```

...without rewriting the table.

**Is this correct?**

If so, do you know where some definitive info on the topic exists in the Postgres docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `ALTER TABLE` will not require a rewrite.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) says:

> Adding a column with a `DEFAULT` clause or changing the type of an existing column will require the entire table and its indexes to be rewritten.

It is very simple to test:
Try with an empty table and see if the `relfilenode` column in the `pg_class` row for the table changes:

```
SELECT relfilenode FROM pg_class
    WHERE relname = 'table_name';
```

Reading on in the documentation, you see:

> As an exception, when changing the type of an existing column, if the `USING` clause does not change the column contents and the old type is either binary coercible to the new type or an unconstrained domain over the new type, a table rewrite is not needed; but any indexes on the affected columns must still be rebuilt.

Since `varchar(50)` is clearly binary coercible to `varchar(100)`, your case will not require a table rewrite, as the above test should confirm.

Comment: The value returned by the query I pasted into your answer has changed after running the `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN TYPE varchar(100)` command. It was `49626` and is now `50237`.

Comment: Did I do something wrong or is there another way to do this? The last time we tried to do a change that required a rewrite in production we had to cancel it after hours of waiting, so nothing with a rewrite will work.

Comment: I have revised my answer and added a documentation link. I see nothing wrong with your previous approach, except that messing with the catalogs is always dangerous. I'd use `text` as data type if you are not certain about a size limit - it is treated the same internally.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help, Laurenz.

Comment: The part with the DEFAULT values is no longer true as of Postgres 11

Comment: Note that since 9.2 until today, the documentation has been wrong about this point: "any indexes on the affected columns must still be rebuilt." 9.2 fixed that, but the docs didn't get updated. [Discussion here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMp9%3DExXtH0NeF%2BLTsNrew_oXycAJTNVKbRYnqgoEAT01t%3D67A%40mail.gmail.com).

Comment: @mlissner Sure - write a doc patch that adds a sentence to that effect!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yep, got a patch submitted for this documentation tweak last night.

Answer (score 3):

According to [What's new in PostgreSQL 9.2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#Reduce_ALTER_TABLE_rewrites) <s>the above answer is at least strange to me</s> the accepted answer was edited to align with the below:

> Reduce ALTER TABLE rewrites
>
> A table won't get rewritten anymore during
>   an ALTER TABLE when changing the type of a column in the following
>   cases:
>
> **varchar(x) to varchar(y) when y>=x**. It works too if going from
>   varchar(x) to varchar or text (no size limitation)

I tested with postgres 10.4 and the *relfilenode* remained the same after running `alter table ... alter column ... type varchar(50)`

```
create table aaa (field varchar(10));
insert into aaa select f from generate_series(1,1e6) f;
commit;
SELECT oid, relfilenode FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'aaa';
alter table aaa alter column field type varchar(50);
commit;
SELECT oid, relfilenode FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'aaa';
```

I'm not sure why you got a different relfilenode in 9.6 (or I'm missing something...).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't check the details. I have fixed my answer because I didn't want to let something wrong stand, even though that clashes your first sentence.

Comment: I have modified the first sentence accordingly.